# Set Dynamic Schema on Runtime using JndiObjectFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

My client wanted to have a dynamic schema on runtime. What I did right now was something like this:

For my web.xml (just important parts only):

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myservlet/sample1/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myservlet/sample2/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/servlet1-servlet.xml
    /WEB-INF/servlet2-servlet.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>

... some properties ...

<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>DATASOURCE_1</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>DATASOURCE_2</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

For my servlet1-servlet.xml(content for servlet2-servlet.xml is the same except for the JNDI name and its default schema)

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="DATASOURCE_1" />
        <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>ph.prj.domain.models</value>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
       <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">SCHEMA1</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="${jdbc.databaseName}" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="${init-db}" />
    <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>
```

And lastly for my method that handles dynamic jndi name on runtime:

```
protected void setCurrentSchema(String identifier) throws Exception {
    if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(IdentifierEnum.SCHEMA_1.getValue(), identifier) || 
            StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(IdentifierEnum.SCHEMA_2.getValue(), identifier)) {
        // WEBSPHERE
        JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource = context.getBean(JndiObjectFactoryBean.class);
        dataSource.setJndiName(ApplicationConstants.JNDI_ROOT_NAME + identifier);

    } else {
        logger.debug(String.format("INVALID identifier SPECIFIED - %s", identifier));
        throw new RequestParamException(String.format("INVALID identifier SPECIFIED - %s", identifier));
    }
}
```

And inorder to access my api, I need to call using the ff. context path:

> /myservlet/sample1/
>
> /myservlet/sample2/

Unfortunately, my client doesn't want the sample1/sample2 part in the context path.

Client wants to access as

> /myservlet/

only, regardless of the schema name.

I am planning to utilize **AbstractRoutingDataSource** from this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)
but then, the sample was using **DriverManagerDataSource** instead of JndiObjectFactoryBean and that, I can't find a method on how to set schema on the fly.

I have this feeling that these methods can help me achieve my desired output *setJndiEnvironment* / *setJndiTemplate* but then, they lack some examples on how to use it and I cannot find some sources that uses those methods to change its schema.

Hopefully you guys can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically set *jpaProperties* on your *JpaTransactionManager* and *LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean* beans at runtime.

```
protected void setCurrentSchema(String identifier) throws Exception {
    if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(IdentifierEnum.SCHEMA_1.getValue(), identifier) || 
        StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(IdentifierEnum.SCHEMA_2.getValue(), identifier)) {
        // WEBSPHERE
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", identifier);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = context.getBean(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = context.getBean(JpaTransactionManager.class);
        transactionManager.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        transactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    } else {
        logger.debug(String.format("INVALID identifier SPECIFIED - %s", identifier));
        throw new RequestParamException(String.format("INVALID identifier SPECIFIED - %s", identifier));
    }
}
```

With this, you can just define a single datasource and won't need to have a default schema since it will be set at runtime. You can also get rid of having multiple *servlet.xml files that is mapped to each of your database schema and mostly, you can get rid of the extra part on your application's context path